# WebBrowser as ListItem and scroll

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-8

This question about WP8 project. 
I have a LongListSelector with pictures and html formatted text below. Currently each pictire implemented as an Item of the list. The last Item with browser has its own template and shows WebBrowser instead of picture. 
I am expected this item behave such as TextBox which I can scroll by interacting with LongListSelector.

But this WebBrowser has it's own scroll inside and intercepts any surrounding scrolling events. Thus whenever I scroll down the list to show WebBrowserControl to the whole screen, I can't go back to the pictures.

Please help me with this issue. What is the appropriate solution? I need a separate pictures since want to implement "Clicked" logic on top of it. And I want to have WebBrowser too (but prefer to behave it similar to RichTextBox (which I can't find in WP8))

Comment: I find solution to prevent gestures interception - it is IsHitTestVisible="False" for the WebBrowser. So now I have another question - is it possible to detect the height of some portion of content inside WebBrowser? I need this to glue 2 or more browsers to make it looks like infinite scrolling.

Comment: Something like this (int)Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('someid').outerHeight" });

Comment: I have implemented gluing but it is very demanding operation. Decided to change the interface to support browser-only window :(

Answer (score 0):

USE ListBox.ItemTemplate  along with DataTemplate and inside dataTemplate we could custom create xaml tag !